# Trying to get the max value from an array in another method while reading from a file

Tags: java, arrays, list, file, arraylist

I have a file with the following data (student id, score)

```
L0111,80.5
L0222,70.8
L0333,95.4
L0444,67.9
L0555,56.5
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is for it to be read with the "readStudentData" method within the ScoreApp class, but be printed the way it is printed within that method currently, but done through the printAll() method. The problem is that I can't access the "items" array within the "readStudentData". Along with this, I can't get the maximum score through the "getMaxScore" method.

My code:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class question5
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
      ScoreApp app = new ScoreApp("C:/Users/USER/workspace/Practical 2/Data/data");
      app.printAll();
      out.println(String.format("%50s", "").replace(' ', '-'));
      out.println("Max score: " + app.getMaxScore());
      out.println("Average score: " + app.getAverageScore());
      out.println("Number of pass scores: " + app.countPassScore());
      out.println("Total score (recursion): " +
      recursiveGetTotalScore(app.getStudents()));
      }
      static double recursiveGetTotalScore(List<Student> list)
      {
        return 0;
      }
      }
class ScoreApp
{
    public static List<Student> students;
    public List<Student> getStudents() //getter method
    {
    return students;
    }
    public ScoreApp(String data) throws IOException
    {
    students = new ArrayList<>();
    readStudentData(data);
    }
    private void readStudentData(String data) throws IOException
    {
        students = new LinkedList<Student>();
        Path path = new File(data).toPath();
        List<String> content = Files.readAllLines(path);
        for(String line : content){
            String[] items = line.split(",");
            String id = items[0];
            double score = Double.valueOf(items[1]);
            Student b = new Student(id, score);
            out.println(items[0]+": "+items[1]);
        }
    }
    public void printAll()
    {

    }
    public double getMaxScore()
    {
        double MaxScore = items[1];
        for(int i=1;i < items[1].length; i++)
            if(items[i] > MaxScore)
                MaxScore = items[i];
                out.println("Maximum score: " + MaxScore);
    }
    public double getAverageScore()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    public int countPassScore()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    }

class Student
{
private String ID;
private double score;
public Student(String ID, double score)
{
    this.ID = ID;
    this.score = score;
}
public String getID()
{
    return this.ID;
}
public void setID(String ID)
{
    this.ID = ID;
}
public double getscore()
{
    return this.score;
}
public void setscore(double score)
{
    this.score = score;
}
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense that `readStudentData` is void prints out data. Don't have it print anything and instead have it return a list of students.

Comment: or even have it still return nothing since it populates a member variable.  In `printAll` iterate through  `ScoreApp.students` and print each one (or have them print themselves ... `for (Student student : students) { student.print() }`

Comment: And remember to add `b` to `students` in the for loop in `readStudentData`

Comment: I just tried that @Tibrogargan, but by doing "    out.println(student);" under printAll(), i'm left with it printing "Student@4e25154f" etc.

Comment: Then give it a decent `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `List<Student> students` in your ScoreApp class. In your “`readStudentData`” method you should be populating/inserting data into that list and in your “`getMaxScore()`” method you should be using that list.

```
public double getMaxScore() {
    double maxScore = 0;
    //"students" is the class variable / list you have in your ScoreApp class
    for(Student current: students) {
        double currentScore = current.getScore();
        if(currentScore > maxScore)
            maxScore = currentScore;
    }
    return maxScore;
}
```

Update: For average score.

```
public double getAverageScore() {
    double averageScore = 0;
    int noOfStudents = 0;
    int sumOfScores = 0;

    for(Student current: students) {
        double currentScore = current.getScore();
        sumOfScores += currentScore;
        noOfStudents++;
        averageScore = sumOfScores / noOfStudents;
    }
    return averageScore;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, how would I go about getting the average score?

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: variable names start with lower case letters

Comment: Thanks for your input! I was only trying to keep things coherent with the remainder of his file. Anyways, I have updated the answer.